# msgget: no such file or directory found

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define msgsz 8
typedef struct msgbuffer
{
long mtype;
char mtext[msgsz];
}
mbuffer;
int main()
{
key_t key;
int msqid,buffer;
mbuffer mb;
key=1234;
if((msqid=msgget(key,0666))<0)
{
perror("msgget");
return 0;
}
if(msgrcv(msqid,&mb,msgsz,1,0)<0)
{
perror("msgrev");
return 1;
}
printf(" MESSAGE : %s IS RECEIVED\n",mb.mtext);
return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error msgget:no such file or directory found
can someone suggest why it is so and probably provide me with a code that can be executable?

Answer (score 0):

> can someone suggest why it is so and probably provide me with a code that can be executable?

It is so because no message queue with the given key exists. You have to create the queue by specifying `IPC_CREAT` in the second argument: `msgget(key, IPC_CREAT|0666)`.